# Can I overwrite the hyperparameters of an Optuna trial object after it has already suggested values?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, optuna

Occasionally Optuna will suggest a sample that I don't really want to evaluate - usually either because it is the same as, or too close to, a previously evaluated solution. In this case I would like to evaluate a random sample instead.

Is there a way to overwrite the suggested values from `trial.suggest_float()` (for example) for a single trial and pass that back to the optimiser?

Given two methods: `eval_check()`, which takes a list of variables and makes a determination as to whether the sample should be evaluated or not, returning `True` if it is to be evaluated and `False` if not; and,`evaluate()` which takes a list of variables and evaluates them, returning a real number - below is a sketch of what I am trying to achieve.

```py
import numpy as np
import random

class Objective(object):
   def __call__(self, trial):
       # suggest values
       x1 = trial.suggest_float('x1', 0.0, 1.0)
       x2 = trial.suggest_int('x2', 10, 20)
       x3 = trial.suggest_categorical('x3', ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'])

       # check if we should evaluate, if not get random value
       while not eval_check([x1, x2, x3]):
           x1 = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
           x2 = np.random.randint(10, 20)
           x3 = random.choice(['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'])

       return evaluate([x1, x2, x3])


sampler = optuna.samplers.NSGAIISampler(population_size=100)     
study = optuna.create_study(sampler=sampler)
study.optimize(Objective(),n_trials=1000)
```

Now, I know this won't work as I want it to, because, say the Optuna `trial` object suggests the sample `[0.5, 15, 'cat2']` but `eval_check` doesn't like that sample and so suggests the random sample `[0.2, 18, 'cat1']`, if I return the output of `evaluate([0.2, 18, 'cat1'])`, then Optuna will think this is the output of `evaluate([0.5, 15, 'cat2'])` and associate that score with that sample in its model.

Is there a way that I can overwrite the suggested hyperparameters in the `trial` object such that when I return the score, Optuna will associate that score with the new overwritten hyperparameters in its model?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I can overwrite the suggested hyperparameters in the trial object such that when I return the score, Optuna will associate that score with the new overwritten hyperparameters in its model?

Optuna doesn't assume users overwrite a parameters of trial. Instead, how about adding a constraint to the search space?

- constrained optimization in Optuna: https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0.0-a2/faq.html?highlight=constrained#how-can-i-optimize-a-model-with-some-constraints

Or, raising `optuna.TrialPruned` for an undesired combination of parameters also skips a computing objective function when `not eval_check([x1, x2, x3])` becomes `True`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so I have to either add a constraint or prune the trial, but can't force it to add a random evaluation to the model?

Comment: I recommend it. At least, Optuna doesn't provide a public interface to overwrite parameter values of created trials.